Why is Excel giving me a wrong solution to a system of equations?
I am trying to get Excel to solve an undeterminate system of four linear equations with four unknowns. My four initial equations are

2,236 + x = (4/10) * (5,676 + x + y + z + w)
1,764 + y = (3/10) * (5,676 + x + y + z + w)
1,120 + z = (2/10) * (5,676 + x + y + z + w)
556 + w = (1/10) * (5,676 + x + y + z + w)

I first re-write my equations as follows:

-(6/10) * x + (4/10) * y + (4/10) * z + (4/10) * w = -34.40
(3/10) * x - (7/10) * y + (3/10) * z + (3/10)* w = 61.20
(2/10) * x + (2/10) * y - (8/10) * z + (2/10) * w = -15.20
(1/10) * x + (1/10) * y + (1/10) * z - (9/10) * w = -11.60

I then take cells F2 to J5 and fill them like this:
-6/10 4/10 4/10 4/10 -34.40
3/10 -7/10 3/10 3/10 61.20
2/10 2/10 -8/10 2/10 -15.20
1/10 1/10 1/10 -9/10 -11.60

I then introduce the following formula in J2
=MMULT(MINVERSE(F2:I5),J2:J5)

Which returns the following values in cells J2 to J5:
-1,792
-1,536
-880
-440

It is straightforward to verify with WolframAlpha or Mathematica that these values do not solve my initial system of equations. So, my questions are:

Why is Excel giving me the wrong answer to my system of equations?
How can I get Excel to give me a correct solution to my system of equations?


Mathematically the determinant of F2:I5 is 0, so MINVERSE(F2:I5) shall not exist; but because of the fact that floating point arithmetic in Excel cannot express numbers like 1/10 without error, in your calculation the inverse exists. Related: Why is this simple Excel calculation not netting Zero?

Thank you very much for your comment—it is very insightful. Do you have any hint on how to approach my problem? I have done the computations by hand and with the help of WolframAlpha, and the result I am looking to obtain in Excel is x=116, y=0, w=56, z=32.

"the result I am looking to obtain in Excel is…" – There is a continuum of possible results, each one is as good as any other. To get a single result you need an arbitrary additional constraint. In the computation of the result you are talking about the (silent) constraint was probably y=0.

Yes, you’re completely right. I know that one of my unknowns will always be 0. So I have to let Excel know which of those unknowns will be 0, and then resolve my new system with 3 unknowns and four equations, which will be overdetermined but will have a solution (something I know by the nature of the problem). Am I right?

There are infinitely many solutions, such as 3.493333, -6.08, 1.5466666, 1.1733333. You could perhaps try to use pseudo-inverses to get a particular solution. I got this one using Moore Penrose pseudo-inverse in Python.

"I know that one of my unknowns will always be 0" – This may be your constraint, but it does not have to be; I mean it's not built into the problem itself. In case of this particular system you can impose an arbitrary value to any single unknown and calculate the three remaining unknowns accordingly – and you will get a solution.

Also I think the second system is incorrect. How do you get that 556 - (1/10) 5.676 equals -11.60 ? If you add all the equations in the first system, it looks impossible.

@Gribouillis Thank you for your comments. I don’t know any Python, so that’s not an option. The thing is that I know right away by simple visual inspection which of my unknowns will be zero. I just checked 556-(1/10)*5,676 equals -11.60. As far as I can tell, it’s correct as per my computer’s calculator.

@KamilMaciorowski Thank you for your comments. I am now trying to do what you suggested in your last comment, but I am having a different problem, which is inverting a particular submatrix. See my new post here: https://superuser.com/questions/1859310/how-to-invert-a-particular-submatrix

@EoDmnFOr3q sorry I thougt it was 5.676 instead of 5576. However, the first system gives you a parametrization of the solution space. Choose arbitrarily the value of s = x + y + z + w. The first system gives you directly a particular solution for this value of s.

By the way, your first rewrite should be to multiply all four equations by 10.  This makes everything integer, and math can work out cleaner and more exact.

If the system of equations is indeterminate, its determinant is equal to 0. In Excel, due to rounding, it can be a number close to zero. Then an attempt to solve such a system will give a random result. In this case, treat one of the unknowns as a parameter and omit one of the equations (which is a linear combination of the others). If you know that in your case y = 0 you can treat y as a parameter and find a solution for the other 3 unknowns.
The general solution can take into account any value of y and appropriately adjusted values of the other variables.

(In my case, the decimal separator is a comma.)

The problem here also has to do with the speed-ups performed to do a matrix determinant (or inversion, etc...).  To do the base calculation of the determinant of an n by n matrix requires the addition of n factorial terms, each of which multiplies n factors, and maybe a negation.  If you start with integers, this never gets rounding errors (unless your numbers get too big).  While this is easy enough for a small matrix, trying it on a 20 by 20 would never finish.  So instead some "simplifications" are done.  These simplifications involve divisions, and so we get rounding error.
Testing on gnumeric (an opensource Excel equivalent), I find that a 2x2 matrix apparently just does the base calculation, but anything larger doesn't.  I tend to get 0 being 8.9E-29 or smaller.
