How to invert a particular submatrix?
Suppose I have a matrix of numbers like this one in cells F2 to I5:
a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 x
b_1 b_2 b_3 b_4 y
c_1 c_2 c_3 c_4 z
d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4 w

Suppose that I want to solve the system of equations given by
a_1 a_3 a_4 x
c_1 c_3 c_4 z
d_1 d_3 d_4 w

Notice that the second matrix is the first one once we eliminate the second row and the second column.
I want to solve the system of equations given by the second matrix using MMULT and MINVERSE. However, MINVERSE does not let me select the values that I need from the first matrix, for it requires an array as input.
One option is to manually write the second matrix out of the first one and solve accordingly. While this works, it seems cumbersome. Is there anyway to use MMULT and MINVERSE to solve the system of equations given by the second matrix without having to write it explicitly (that is, telling MINVERSE which cells to pick from the first matrix).
I have also tried the sorting feature, but that breaks down many of the formulas in my spreadsheet, so it’s not an option.
So I guess that my question is: how can I invert a particular submatrix?

You could just make b_2 temporarily a large number. Or, or temporarily add a large number to the value of b_2.

Thank you for your comment. I guess I could, but I feel the approach with CHOOSECOLS and CHOOSEROWS is quite elegant.

If you have Excel365, you can combine CHOOSECOLS and CHOOSEROWS functions to get the desired results. These functions allow to select/choose columns and rows respectively from a given array.
Try:
=CHOOSECOLS(CHOOSEROWS(C4:G7,1,3,4),1,3,4,5)

OR
=CHOOSEROWS(CHOOSECOLS(C4:G7,1,3,4,5),1,3,4)



Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to use CHOOSECOLS AND CHOOSEROWS as an input for MINVERSE? I am asking it because I really don’t need to see the matrix I’m performing the inverse on.

@EoDmnFOr3q As far as I know, It should be possible.

I am trying it, and I don’t seem to be able to… To be precise, I get a value error. Any further help?

@EoDmnFOr3q Are your inputs numbers? There should be the same number of columns and rows when using MINVERSE function.

I just got what I needed. Thank you very much!

You can treat the problem more generally and define a LAMBDA function that will return an array with the omitted row and column with the given numbers. I will give two variants of the definition of such a function:
=LAMBDA(data,r,c, FILTER(FILTER(data, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data))<>r), SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data))<>c))
=LAMBDA(data,r,c, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(data)-1, COLUMNS(data)-1, LAMBDA(x,y, INDEX(data, IF(x<r,x,x+1), IF(y<c,y,y+1)))))

A function can be named e.g. SUBMATRIX and called with three arguments: data range, row_nr to delete, column_nr to delete.
The result of such a function can be an argument to other array functions.

